# I try to run "npm run prod" on Mac but showing a error. Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:

Tags: node.js, typescript

Error massage is:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: 
/Volumes/jack/company/et e ch/projects/node_modules/p o s t c s s - cli/in dex. j s
at Object.Module._extensions..j s (internal/modules/c j s/loader. j s: 1173:13)
at Module.load (internal/modules/c j s/lo ader .j s:1001:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/c j s/loader . j s:900:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/ run_main .j s:74:12)
at internal/main/run_main_m o d u l e . j s :18:47
code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
```

What should i do?

Comment: We need more info, such as what is the `prod` script?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.